# Does loc in pandas use vectorised logic or a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I access rows in pandas with the loc function as below:

```
pdf.loc[pdf.a>2]
```

Is this vectorised? Is it better than using numpy

```
pdf[pdf.a>2]
```

Comment: Following up from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426247/vectorized-update-to-pandas-dataframe/34426589?noredirect=1#comment98407630_34426589

Comment: i think `loc[]` is better then a for loop when you do a conditional update based on columns.

Comment: `numpy` will be faster, but then you lose the indices, which are super useful and inherent to pandas. `pdf.to_numpy()[np.where(pdf.a > 2)[0]]` should be faster than `.loc`

Answer (score 1):

This timing suggests there is no slow down with loc

```
testa = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10000000),columns =['q'])
%timeit testb = testa.loc[testa.q>6] 
%timeit testc = testa[testa.q>7]
```

```
1 loop, best of 3: 207 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 208 ms per loop
```

Comment: Reading a bit more into this, vectorisation just means that the for loop is done at the c level. Presumably this can be done in loc.

One other thing I'm confused about is why the loc command uses [ ] rather than ( ). Presumably this implies something about what loc is doing that I have never understood.